# Data format tips - USDA - Agri Commodities

Tags: python, xml, text, web-scraping, xls

guys, 
I am trying to develop a python solution to get some information about agri commodities from the US Department of Agriculture (USDA).

Every month, the USDA releases a report with estimates for commodities such as corn, soy and wheat.

My goal is to prepare a program that goes to the website, get the right number and return a message such as:

--USDA estimated Soybean US production in 4,48 b tons, upper than 4,20 b tons in the previous report

**But to start it I need to figure out which is the best type of file to get this informations from. Which would be easier to deal with all this information? What do you think?**

The USDA release the same data base in PDF, xls, XML and TXT. (you can see the files here: http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/MannUsda/viewDocumentInfo.do?documentID=1194)

I was thinking of get it from the xls, which is a type of file I handle better. But looking at the data base I see some differences from data base to data base. The txt and XML files seems to be more accurate... but I've never worked with it... don't know if it is a good idea.

BTW: If you have some suggestions of library to work with the files and data I also accept. =D

Thank you!

Comment: This question is not so much about coding as a recommendation on how to approach something. These questions are off topic for SO, but you may get some help on the [python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). IMAO, this data is too poorly organized to not just completely re-format it in excel first. Then you can just export it as something easy to work with like csv.

Comment: Yeah.... It is too bad organized. But I have no option. I got to use this every single month. It's crazy to find the information for every commodity, Do you have any tip of how automatize the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the XML format which is the most machine-readable and will have the most support. In the past I've used the XML parsing library called `lxml` with `BeautifulSoup` to pull out the data I needed. Both of these have lots of documentation.

Comment: the xml indicated seems to have an odd structure with non-intuitive tag names. frankly none of the data is well organized at all, and will need quite a lot of manual effort

Comment: Sounds like most XML I've worked with. That's why a library like BeautifulSoup can be helpful cause you can pull out odd bits of XML as long as the oddness is consistent between months.

Comment: It's some nasty data for sure..

Comment: I was thinking about XML, too. 
The excel file would be my first option if I would like to open just one month and that's all... But I want to automatize the process. I don't want to have to open this file and search for the names I want every single time. It's a lot of work. I got to open the perspective for plantation, area, yield and a lot more for every commodity. =[

Comment: Do you have any tip of good books or sites to help me with this mission?

Comment: I used a variety of tutorials, but this one on web scraping looks quite complete: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/. Scraping XML and HTML work very similarly.